# Invalid "ios-version" error in titanium

Tags: ios

We are using ios-7, x-code 5.0 in titanium application with alloy frame work
When i try to upgrade(i used for upgrade option from help menu under available titanium updates) my titanium sdk version 3.1.3 to 3.2.0 and cli versino 3.12. to 3.2.0. After completion of up gradation when i try to run my application am getting the below error

[ERROR] : Invalid "--ios-version" value "7.0"
Accepted values:
7.0.3
Accepted values:
[ERROR] : Invalid "--sim-version" value "7.0"
7.0.3

Please guide me....
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what I did is build the version using the cli tool directly from the terminal inside titanium ide, using 3.1.3 (having problems with 3.2.0 and map/location component).
Just revert your tiapp.xml to 3.1.3 again.
navigate to your project folder inside the terminal and type:

```
ti build --platform ios --sdk 3.1.3.GA
```

and it will build the project correctly.